# Custom Validation Attribute With Multiple Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I am trying to build a custom ValidationAttribute to validate the number of words for a given string:

```
public class WordCountValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value, int count)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            var text = value.ToString();
            MatchCollection words = Regex.Matches(text, @"[\S]+");
            return words.Count <= count;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

However, this does not work as IsValid() only allows for a single parameter, the value of the object being validated, so I can't override the method in this way.

Any ideas as to how I can accomplish this while still using the simple razor format:

```
        [ViewModel]
        [DisplayName("Essay")]
        [WordCount(ErrorMessage = "You are over the word limit."), Words = 150]
        public string DirectorEmail { get; set; }

        [View]
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Essay)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I might be missing something obvious -- that happens to me a lot -- but could you not save the maximum word count as an instance variable in the constructor of WordCountValidator? Sort of like this:

```
public class WordCountValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    readonly int _maximumWordCount;

    public WordCountValidator(int words)
    {
        _maximumWordCount = words;
    }

    // ...
}
```

That way when you call `IsValid()`, the maximum word count is available to you for validation purposes. Does this make sense, or like I said, am I missing something?

Comment: That works perfectly! After setting up the constructor as you demonstrated I was able to simply add the new custom validator as an annotation for the field:

[WordCountValidator(150, ErrorMessage = "Over the allowed word limit")]

Comment: Glad to hear :-) I guess sometimes the best solutions are the simple ones!